# Generate a random number from randint() multiple times in a function in Python

Tags: python

I'm very new to python and am trying to create a basic I Ching Hexagram creation program, and I'm running into issues in my first function.

```
import random    

def hexline(): 
#This flips three coins and produces a hexagram line 
    flip = random.randint(2,3)
    res = flip+flip+flip
    if res == 6:
        print('-- --x')
    elif res == 7:
        print('-----')
    elif res == 8:
        print('-- --')
    elif res == 9:
        print('-----x')
```

When `hexline()` is run, it only returns either `-----x` or `-- --x` (values of 9 or 6) indicating that `randint(2,3)` is only making one random selection for the whole function (rather than 3 distinct random choices) and adding them together with `res`. So `res` is producing only `2+2+2` or `3+3+3`, rather than say `3+2+3` or `2+2+3`. How might I generate a random selection multiple times in this function, rather than only once? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say `flip = random.randint(2,3)`, it calls the `randint` just once and sets the output value to `flip`. Therefore, adding together three flips just multiplies the value by three.

A very simple fix is to create three variables, `flip1`, `flip2`, `flip3` each with a call to `randint`, then add these variables together to form `res`. Alternatively, add them all together at once.

As you progress with Python, you'll learn that you can produce similar effects with a for loop or list comprehension. You can use these to add things together an arbitrary number of times. Here's the for loop version:

```
total = 0
for i in range(1, 4):
    total = total + random.randint(2,3)
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
import random    

def hexline(): 
#This flips three coins and produces a hexagram line 
    res=0
    for x in range(0,3):
      res += random.randint(2,3)
    if res == 6:
        print('-- --x')
    elif res == 7:
        print('-----')
    elif res == 8:
        print('-- --')
    elif res == 9:
        print('-----x')
```

Answer (score 0):

here, you're assigning a value to `flip` once, and you are not evaluating the randomness a second time. This means that you are effectively evaluating something more along the lines of this:

```
    a = 2
    res = a + a + a
```

Naturally, the above code should evaluate to `6`, or `9` when the flip generates a `3`.

To solve the problem you are experiencing, you need to evaluate the `random.randint(2,3)` three times, rather than the one you are doing right now, like so:

```py
import random    

def hexline(): 
#This flips three coins and produces a hexagram line 

    res = random.randint(2,3) + random.randint(2,3) + random.randint(2,3)
    if res == 6:
        print('-- --x')
    elif res == 7:
        print('-----')
    elif res == 8:
        print('-- --')
    elif res == 9:
        print('-----x')
```

You could define a small function or a `lambda` to make this a little neater.

```py
import random    

def hexline(): 
#This flips three coins and produces a hexagram line 
    flip = lambda: random.randint(2,3)
    res = flip()+flip()+flip()
    if res == 6:
        print('-- --x')
    elif res == 7:
        print('-----')
    elif res == 8:
        print('-- --')
    elif res == 9:
        print('-----x')
```

what happens here is nearly identical to the first solution, but it kind of renames the `random.randint(2,3)` to `flip()` by defining it as the lambda.